# How to generate random php slug/url and insert in database?

Tags: php, random, slug

i want to generate 6 character random url for each post like  ac7Lmn,uYoXo etc when user clicks submit button .

if the slug already exists in database then generate another.

i need short random url like youtube "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95I5VaR7GeU"

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];



$post_slug = [WHAT CAN I DO HERE  ]  




if( $post_image==''    ) {
echo "<p>  upload an image please</p>";


}

else{

$insert ="insert into posts (post_image,post_slug) values ('$post_image','$post_slug' ) "; 

}


} ?>
```

Comment: You should give an example of what you tried so far. Please check help center for articles about how to write good questions (and answers)

Comment: you didn't found anything when you searched for "how generate random string php"?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky i  am not here to ask how to write a good question ...i am here to find some help

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is not to generate a random slug but to encode the value of primary key (id) using [Hashids](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php) library.

Why? Because you remove the problem of generating a unique string. Since `id` is already unique, simply deliver it to the client encoded. When you receive this string, decode it. If decoding fails, your client provided an invalid hashid.

#### Encoding example

```
use Hashids\Hashids;

$hashids = new Hashids();

$hashids->encode(1);
```

#### Decoding example

```
use Hashids\Hashids;

$hashids = new Hashids();

$id = $hashids->encode(1); 
$number = $hashids->decode($id);
```

This approach is quick and efficient and you can set your own custom alphabet for purposes of encoding.

If you go down the route of generating a unique string, you need to deal with unique keys and custom algorithm for generating this unique string. Since `id` will always be unique, you're going to repeat something that's done for you by MySQL.